# how to force jquery attr() to add the attribute with single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I create an in memory div:

```
var video_div = document.createElement('div');
video_div.className = "vidinfo-inline";
```

In essence I have some variables:

```
var key = "data-video-srcs";
var value = '{"video1":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdxEAt91D7k&list=TLhaPoOja-0f4","video2":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVlaZfLlWQc&list=TLalXwg9bTOmo"}';
```

And I use jquery to add that data attribute to the div:

```
$(video_div).attr(key, value);
```

Here is my problem. After doing that I get this:

```
<div class="vidinfo-inline" data-video-srcs="{"video1":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdxEAt91D7k&list=TLhaPoOja-0f4","video2":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVlaZfLlWQc&list=TLalXwg9bTOmo"}"></div>
```

And that doesn't work putting that json in there. It has to be in single quotes. It has to look like this:

```
<div class="vidinfo-inline" data-video-srcs='{"video1":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdxEAt91D7k&list=TLhaPoOja-0f4","video2":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVlaZfLlWQc&list=TLalXwg9bTOmo"}'></div>
```

As later on I do something like this:

```
var video_srcs = $('.vidinfo-inline').data('video-srcs');
```

And that won't work unless the json is in single quotes.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

According to jquery: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

Thus I can't escape the double quotes, it has to be inside single quotes. I have a work around and I'll post that as an answer unless someone else has a better answer.

Comment: Why do you put data to `data-video-srcs`? If you already have it in javascript - why not to store it there?

Comment: I am building an authoring interface. It essentially will output the html that someone needs to put in their own page that the javascript will then interact with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a workaround. And if anyone has a better solution, I'd love to see it.

I wrote a replace method:

```
var fixJson = function(str) {
  return String(str)
    .replace(/"{/g, "'{")
    .replace(/}"/g, "}'");
};
```

So basically I send the html into this function and insert it into the DOM.

For example:

```
var html = htmlUnescape($('#temp_container').html());
html = fixJson(html);
```

I realize that has some code smell to it. I mean, going through everything on that element just to fix the double quotes to single quotes stinks. But for lack of other options or ideas, it works. :\

Answer (score 2):

Replace the double quotes with HTML entities:

```
var value = '{"video1":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdxEAt91D7k&list=TLhaPoOja-0f4","video2":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVlaZfLlWQc&list=TLalXwg9bTOmo"}';

# Naive approach:
value = value.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('"', '&quot;');

# Using jQuery:
var $tmp = jQuery('<div></div>');
value = $tmp.text(value).html();

// Then store it as normal
```

Comment: This is a no go. When I select that element with jquery it parses the data and it will see the data-video-srcs = "{\"

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bfcoder/cFLEN/ Look at the console log.

Comment: @fguillen that is not valid JSON. It has to be {"foo":"bar"} The JSON must be formatted with double quotes.