# Jquery attr() method adding double quotes instead of single quotes

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add the following code using Jquery on runtime to a div having id="container"

```
data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": 1000 }'
```

I am using the attr() method to get the job done:

```
$('#container').attr("data-flickity",'{ "autoPlay": 500 }');
```

Now the problem is the end result in HTML is that the attribute's value is getting enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes like this,

```
data-flickity="{ "autoPlay": 1000 }"
```

and due to this, my webpage is not working as it should.

**So anyone knows how to tell the attr() method to add single quotes OR any other way to achieve the attribute addition with single quotes?**

EDIT: [Here's a Codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RNQwaB) to what I am trying to implement. Since I cannot access the HTML .. I am trying to add attributes using JS.

Comment: Have you tried: $('#container').attr("data-flickity","{ 'autoPlay': 500 }"); ?

Comment: Just tried ... this doesn't even add the attribute.

Comment: Is this some type of template like Handlebars? `data-flickity="{ "autoPlay": 1000 }"` Can you provide an example of what the HTML supposed to look like?

Comment: Here's a code pen to what I am trying to implement .. but the thing is I don't have access to the core HTML .. and that's exactly why I am trying to slip the attributes using JS : https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RNQwaB

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579528/how-to-force-jquery-attr-to-add-the-attribute-with-single-quotes

Answer (score 1):

And why not simply use the single quotes on the inner part instead of the outer?

The string `{ 'autoPlay': 500 }`is passed to the browser... Not its wrapping quotes.

```js
$('#container').attr("data-flickity","{ 'autoPlay': 500 }");
console.log( $('#container').attr("data-flickity") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">container</div>
```